# Get Current login user email address dropbox

Tags: dropbox

Dropbox,How can I get the information of current login user in c#.
like username,email address of desktop dropbox client.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dropbox API offers account information via the /account/info endpoint:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#account-info

The documentation there also covers which pieces of information are available.

Dropbox doesn't offer an official C# SDK, so you can either use the HTTP endpoint above directly, or use a third party library. There are some listed here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/other